# PHP: Get the "number of bits per limb" in GNU MP

Tags: php, random, gnu, gmp, bit

I want to use the function [gmp_random()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-random.php) by GNU MP in PHP.
I need to set the exact value of bits I want (for example a random number with 64bit length).

The limiter parameter is multiplied with the "number of bits per limb". How can I get this value?
Is that ever equivalent to the bit-count of the CPU or is there any PHP function to get the value?

In the original library it is represent by the const [mp_bits_per_limb](http://gmplib.org/manual/Useful-Macros-and-Constants.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's no simple way to solve that.

You can either pretend that mp_bits_per_limb equals PHP_INT_SIZE*8 and just use that (will work on most, but not all architectures). The resulting bugs will be tough and a worthy thing to debug for any developer. So this is probably the way to go :)

Or work around it by knowing that mp_bits_per_limb will not be smaller than 16, so you just use "number_of_bits_you_want/16", get a result that has too many bits and gmp_and() your result with 0xFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF to cut it down to 16, 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a patch which fix it now: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62375

The patch will register the constant "GMP_LIMB_BITS" in PHP.